# What do InProcServer32 Keys and ThreadingModel Strings in Registry Editor do?

Tags: windows, registry

What do Windows Registry Editor "InProcServer32" Keys and "ThreadingModel" Strings do? Newbie explanation please.

I want to add custom shell folders to ThisPC. I am using existing Shell Folders like Control Panel Applets or UserFolders as guides. I am not editing existing entries but rather creating new ones and I am reasonably experienced with windows customization through the registry but I am not a coder/programmer.

For InProcServer32 Keys, the main choices for Control Panel Applets and ThisPC Folders seem to be either shell32.dll and windows.storage.dll. What is the difference between the two and how do I choose? There doesn't seem to be any icons associated with windows.storage.dll so InProcServer32 doesn't look like it is points to resources.

For ThreadingModel, seems like the major choices are "apartment" and "both". Again, what is the difference between the two and how do I know what to choose?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

These keys are [COM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/com/component-object-model--com--portal) related.

InProcServer32 points to the library where the class is actually implemented (where the computer code lives). ThreadingModel is the COM threading model that results in STA, NTA or MTA. "Apartment" (STA) is the safe choice if you don't know.

Picking the correct InProcServer32 is a bit of a problem if you did not code your own library. Windows is allowed to move the implementation around from version to version. The only [documented](https://web.archive.org/web/20190903150533/http://msdn2.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms997573.aspx) library for non-programmers is actually shdocvw.dll. In your case you basically have to find a existing feature and copy the library it uses.